# Reset status bar tmux after exiting an ssh connection started within a tmux window

Tags: bash, ssh, tmux

I tried many things but tmux seems to be very stubborn on this one.

When I start a tmux session in bash it shows

`0:bash*`

in my status bar. Then when I ssh to a server it gives me

`0:user@server:~*`

When I then exit the ssh session, the status bar does not revert to the previous

`0:bash*`, it just keeps the `0:user@server:~*`

which is annoying to me. I checked the man page, searched the internets, but hope the hive mind can assist me here.

This is all I have in my .tmux.conf,

```
set -g mouse on
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

`tmux -V` outputs `tmux 2.6`

Comment: [1] Check `/etc/tmux.conf` [2] Try `set-option status off` then `set-option status on` to check [3] Check `PROMPT_COMMAND` on local machine & on SSH machine

Comment: I don't have a ```/etc/tmux.conf``` and when I try [2] and then start a tmux session it hangs with a warning: ```/home/me/.tmux.conf:14: no current session```

Comment: Here, [2] was supposed to be "executed" in the current session ( not in a new session ) via "CTRL-B COLON set-option status off" then "CTRL-B COLON set-option status on" ! Ok, Did you check [3] ? Your Post gives 2 lines on tmux conf, but the error message Points to line 14 ! Are there more lines in your tmux conf ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback, will try it later (executing as command). There are more lines in my ```.tmux.conf```, but all but the 2 I mentioned are commented out.

Comment: resetting status option doesnt change it back. ```PROMPT_COMMAND``` on ssh machine indeed sets the user and server in tmux's status bar, but when exiting from remote machine, the status bar stil does not reset. I searched, but can't find how to set it

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** TMUX changes Status Bar when connecting to SSH Server & **DOES NOT** change it back when exiting that SSH Server.

**Solution :** PROMPT_COMMAND is the Environment Variable which gives the value to be shown in TMUX Status Bar. That is missing on local machine. Put that Exact Setting (taken from SSH Server) in local bash rc file. Exit TMUX & start new TMUX Session.

In SSH Server bash rc file, you may see something like this :

`PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"\033]0;$USER (on $HOSTNAME)\007\""`
`export PROMPT_COMMAND`

Put the Exact Setting in local machine.

New TMUX window or new TMUX Session will work correctly now.

In case that is not helping, then BASH is setting the window title but TMUX is not using it.
Then we have to make TMUX use the title via this :
`CTRL-B COLON set-options -gw windows-status-format "#I:#W#F"`
`CTRL-B COLON set-options -gw windows-status-current-format "#I:#W#F"`
`CTRL-B COLON set-options -gw automatic-rename on`

Now, BASH will be setting the window title & TMUX will be using that.
When SSH changes the window title & then later, SSH Exits, then TMUX will Correctly update the window title.

Comment: It is not missing on local machine. I have git-aware prompt on my local machine, and indeed for NEW tmux windows it shows the correct information on the status bar, but after connecting to SSH server it wont change back after exiting. In my current workflow I now exit that tmux window and start a fresh one, because it is really annoying that it persists the ssh machine's name when the connection is gone.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with GNOME Terminal 3.28.2?

Comment: I have updated my Post , incorporating it with your latest comments ; I think that will work !

Comment: Thanks for all your work, but for new tmux windows it was already working in my setup. My question is specific about an existing tmux window in which i ssh to a remote server and then exit, then statusbar doesn't revert. I now close that tmux window and always start a new one.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I am trying to say that with (1) Correct `PROMPT_COMMAND` & (2) Correct `windows-status-format` & (3) Correct `windows-status-current-format` , you should not get this Issue where "SSH Exit makes title stuck". You should try this & Check. In case it works, you can add the 2 Settings to tmux conf & then "SSH Exit Issue" will not occur again. @SjorsBranderhorst

Comment: I have added one last Setting :: automatic-rename on :: I hope that is the Missing Setting which will Solve the Issue ! @SjorsBranderhorst

Comment: Some Positive News : I am seeing the Exact Same Issue with "automatic-rename off" & Issue goes away with "automatic-rename on" : I think that Missing Setting will Solve the Issue !! @SjorsBranderhorst

Comment: That is progress! After SSH exit it doesnt automatic revert (I have put the option in `.tmux.conf`), but when I set the option after ```CTRL-B:``` it does work. Now we have to crack that tmux does automatically execute this option after exit SSH, or I can make a shortcut for it I guess. Like I would want to use ```CTRL-B CTRL-T``` and it would execute that option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139247/discussion-between-sjors-branderhorst-and-prem).

Comment: Where you have $I, should that be #I ?

Comment: Nice catch , @RobertNewton , I have rectified that typo !

Comment: With that typo rectification , @SjorsBranderhorst , your Issue should be totally resolved now.