# How do I get the tmux window name back after ssh clobbered it?

Tags: ssh, tmux

This is a common problem, and while not critical, it is quite annoying.

While using `tmux` on a remote server, each window is renamed according to the program being run. So if I have 3 windows running `bash` shells, then start `vim` in window 1, the windows will be labeled `0:bash`, `1:vim`, `2:bash`. When I close `vim` all three report `bash`. So far, everything is great.

If `ssh` to certain machines, say `ssh other_user@some_machine`, the `tmux` window name changes to `1:other_user@some_machine:~` which is sort of fine. The problem is, when I close the `ssh` session the name on the window remains.

I know that it's possible to change it manually to something: `:rename-window "Better"` but how do I get the nice auto changing window name back? The only solution I've found thus far, is to close the window and start a new one which gets the default behavior back until I `ssh` to a troubled machine. Note that not all `ssh` connections do the remote machine rename, but some do and they don't revert correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Reset status bar tmux after exiting an ssh connection started within a tmux window](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/717129)